# How to write proper target selector in swift iOS?

Tags: ios, google-maps, uibutton, swift2, xcode7

So I have this button to give direction using google map, the problem is I don't know how to write proper target selector in UIButton since the latest swift

here is my button:

```
directionButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.goToMap(String(format: "%.6f", place.coordinate.latitude), longitude: String(format: "%.6f", place.coordinate.longitude))), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

here is my function :

```
func goToMap(latitude: String, longitude: String) {
        print("function gotoMap works!!!!")
        if (UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(NSURL(string:"comgooglemaps://")!)) {
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string:
                "comgooglemaps://?saddr=&daddr=\(latitude),\(longitude)&directionsmode=driving")!)
        } else {
            print("Can't use comgooglemaps://")

            var addressToLinkTo = ""

            addressToLinkTo = "http://?saddr=&daddr=\(latitude),\(longitude)&directionsmode=driving"

            addressToLinkTo = addressToLinkTo.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

            let url = NSURL(string: addressToLinkTo)
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url!)
        }

}
```

anyone can help me ?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot pass parameter with a `selector`, Modify your method as `goToMap()` and store the latitude & longitude data in instance variable's to use within the function. then you could use

```
directionButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.goToMap()))

func goToMap(){
 // use value stored in instance var
 // self.latitude
 // self.longitude
}
```